# How to access queued_for_write image in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have implemented a preview option for my users which shows a created post in preview mode. Users can upload images there and I am using paperclip + AWS S3 to process the images. I want to show a selected image BEFORE saving it.

Now I came to various methods how to realise that. The best I found was using

```
image.queued_for_write[:original].path
```

as I found paperclip to pass a temporarily URL when processing the image.
That works so far, but when I implement that path in my view, I see this pattern:
    /var/folders/xw/35zfm_dj0h1bcn78z3m1n8d40000gn/T/78805a221a988e79ef3f42d7c5bfd41820150601-34952-1y9eun7.jpg

That does look like a valid path but the image is not loaded and instead, a 404 is returned.

My question is how do I access the temp image path in paperclip so I can make use of a solid preview feature?

Answer (score 1):

`image.queued_for_write[:original].path` is correct, but you cannot just link it in views.

You should instead read and transform it into Base64, which is then passed to the view.

In controller:

```
def preview
  file = image.queued_for_write[:original].path
  file_content = file.read
  @preview = "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.encode64(file_content)
end
```

In view just use the passed preview:

```
<img src="<%= @preview %>" />
```

And it should work fine. I haven't tested this code myself, but I used something very similar in the past.